# Skip First Row in SQL Google Sheets Table

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have the following code that pulls in data from Google Sheets, but there is 1 row of text above the actual table within the spreadsheet. How would I skip the first row and use the headers in the second row, if the row headers are defined in the first part?

I tried adding a LIMIT 1,100000 to the end of the code with no luck

```
DEFINE TABLE temp_table (
  format = 'trix',
  urls = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TxFxscsd',
  worksheet = 'Worksheet1',
  columns = [
    ('this_document_is_based_off', 'STRING', 'This document is based off.')
  ],
  header = true,
  refer_columns_by_header = true);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE google.imo_comms OPTIONS (
  quota_accounting_owner='rcasfdspfsd@yahoo.com'
) AS
SELECT *
FROM temp_table;
```

Comment: can you just make a new worksheet on the Google Sheet called "Worksheet2" then put this in cell A1 of Worksheet2:  ={Worksheet1!A2:Z}  Then change your worksheet variable in sql to 'Worksheet2'?

Comment: I could, but that doesn't seem to be a clean solution... I figured I cannot be the only person to run into this issue